# Better grep to search file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a simple script in bash which uses grep to search in a file.

I want to do the same thing i have below but i dont like the use of using 2 temp files, is there a better way of doing this?

```
    #! /bin/bash

FILE="text.txt"

rm /tmp/temp*
temp_file1=$(mktemp /tmp/temp1)
temp_file2=$(mktemp /tmp/temp2)

cp $FILE $temp_file1

for string in $@
do
grep -i "$string" $temp_file1 > $temp_file2
mv $temp_file2 $temp_file1
done

cat $temp_file1
```

Thanks

Comment: `I know awk is a much faster way of doing` -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88503/using-grep-vs-awk

Comment: oh i always thought awk was faster thanks a lot! updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**`script.sh`**:

```
echo "$@" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/.*/g' | xargs -Ifile grep -E 'file' test.txt`
```

**Example**

Sample contents of **`test.txt`**:

```
This is sample text
Good instance of Test procedure completed, yes
```

On executing **`script.sh`**:

```
./script.sh Good Test yes
Good instance of Test procedure completed, yes
```

Comment: Exactly what i want! So simple! thanks a lot for this.

Comment: But will it match anything if you use `./script.sh Test Good yes`?

Comment: Well maybe it works for higher versions of bash or GNU versions, doesn't run on my system.

Answer (score 2):

I used `awk` not to improve performance but because it fits more your needs (search multiple patterns on same line without regarding the order)

my_script.sh :

```
search=${@:2}
awk -v search="$search" 'BEGIN{nb_patterns=split(search, a)}{p=1;for(i=1;i<=nb_patterns;i++){if(!(tolower($0)~tolower(a[i]))){p=0}}}p' $1
```

test.txt example :

```
hello world
world hello
hello
world
enzjlgz
```

Usage :

```
sh test.sh test.txt HeLlo WorLd
```

Result :

```
hello world
world hello
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to do the same thing, its combining the search words and outputting all the results. I want to combine the search words and only output if they are on the same line in the text file

Comment: Update to above comment: This doesnt seem to do the same thing, its not combining the search words. Its outputting all the results of where the words are individually. I want to combine the search words and only output if they are on the same line in the text file.

Comment: With an awk do you have to state the file? I just want to search in a single file so can this be added within the script?

Comment: Sure look at @Mihir answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quickie perl script that will do it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use List::Util qw/all/;
use Getopt::Long;

my $file;
GetOptions("file=s", \$file);

my @patterns = map { qr/$_/i } @ARGV;

open my $in, "<", $file;
while (my $line = <$in>) {
  print $line if all { $line =~ m/$_/ } @patterns;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ cat test.txt
hello world abc
hello def
world ghi
enzjlgz
it's a world of Jello out there
$ perl findall.pl --file=test.txt '[hj]ello' world
hello world abc
it's a world of Jello out there
```

Comment: Thanks! Would prefer a bash script

Comment: @user3411002 shell scripting is all about combining external programs written in all sorts of languages in order to do useful things. No different than using grep, mv, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash

gawk -v words="$*" '
    BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 ; split(words, words_array, " ") } 

    {
        for (word in words_array) 
        {
            if(index($0, words_array[word]) == 0) 
            {
                next
            }   
        }

        print
    }'  text.txt
```

With `gawk` it can be pretty simpler i guess.